# How to perform automatic cloning of github repository and that repository should be copied in one folder automatically using node js..?

Tags: html, node.js

How to perform automatic cloning of github repository and that repository should be copied in one folder automatically using node js..??

I have used this link http://www.nodegit.org/ and followed all the steps to clone the repository which are given here..but still getting these two error.

%1 is not a valid windows 32 application and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 internal Servor error.

Any help will greatly be appreciated..??

Answer (score 0):

I create a ruby library that allow anyone to clone multiple Github repository easily in one simple command using your own credential.

If you have ruby install then you could run something like

```
$gem install github-cloner
$github-cloner --user awesome_user 
               --base-dir ~/Desktop/github                 
               --languages "JavaScript" 
               --clone
```

Detail installation and sample usage are in the [README.md](https://github.com/agilecreativity/github-cloner) of the project.